# Reference for Nori motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives, motivic-homotopy, nori-motives

I would like to study Nori motives and I am a complete outsider of the subject. I do, however, have background on Chow motives, Voevodsky motives $\mathrm{DM}$ and his stable homotopy category $\mathrm{SH}$.

My question is:

**Do you know an introductory reference and the main papers about Nori motives?**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the best introduction has already been mentioned by Donu Arapura, and it is available online:

- Marc Levine, [Mixed Motives](https://www.uni-due.de/~bm0032/publ/MixMotKHB.pdf) (2005)

Section 1 ("Essentials of Nori Motives") of this paper might also be useful:

- Annette Huber & Stefan Müller-Stach, [On the relation between Nori Motives and Kontsevich Periods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0865) (2011)

Also, there are some interesting unpublished notes on motives by Nori himself:

- Madhav Nori, [Lectures at TIFR](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304034131/http://www.arithgeo.ethz.ch/alpbach2011/Nori_TIFR)

Comment: there is a recent new construction due to Joyal-Cartier; see https://indico.math.cnrs.fr/event/1262/

Comment: @guest Regarding this construction, see Section VIII of https://www.laurentlafforgue.org/math/NoriMotivesInformation.pdf

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I leave here as a comment Thi's reference about Harrer's thesis https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1609/1609.05516.pdf

Comment: @Myshkin   the link to Lectures at TIFR is not working ...can you please update it?

Comment: @S.D. I've updated the link to Nori's notes.

Answer (score 10):

There are brief outlines in various places, such as an article by Marc Levine on motives in the K-theory handbook. However, the most complete reference is the manuscript "Periods and Nori motives" by Annette Huber and Stefan Müller-Stach. I expect that it will be published in the near future. In the meantime, I suspect a copy may be available from one of their web pages, or perhaps you need to ask them.

Comment: It seems there is a copy here https://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/arithgeom/preprints/buch/mantel.html

Answer (score 4):

The PhD thesis of D. Harrer is now available on Arxiv.

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1609/1609.05516.pdf